# What is the difference between UTF-32 and UCS-4?

Tags: string, unicode, encoding, char, utf

What is the difference between UTF-32 and UCS-4 ?
Isn't UTF-32 supposed to be a fixed-width encoding ?

Comment: This question is a useful addition to this site: since it is a programming question, and is not yet answered on this site. Telling someone to 'Google it' is not a valid answer to any question ever - and has no place on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`UTF-32` has started as a subset of `UCS-4`. Now it is identical except that the UTF-32 standard has additional Unicode semantics. See details on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32):

> The original **ISO 10646 standard defines a 31-bit encoding form called
>   UCS-4**, in which each encoded character in the Universal Character Set
>   (UCS) is represented by a 32-bit friendly code value in the code space
>   of integers between 0 and hexadecimal 7FFFFFFF.
>
> Because only 17 planes are actually in use, all current code points
>   are between **0** and **0x10FFFF**. **UTF-32 is a subset of UCS-4** that uses only
>   this range. Since the Principles and Procedures document of
>   JTC1/SC2/WG2 states that all future assignments of characters will be
>   constrained to the BMP or the first 14 supplementary planes, UTF-32
>   will be able to represent all Unicode characters. Accordingly, **UCS-4
>   and UTF-32 are now identical except that the UTF-32 standard has
>   additional Unicode semantics**.

However, I am not exactly sure, what `additional Unicode semantics` means. Maybe someone can provide a better answer.

Comment: I personaly don't know @一二三. Maybe we need a better answer, which has more information about this.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says "[clarification needed]".

Comment: Sounds to me like UCS-4 = [0,0x7FFFFFFF] while UTF-32 = [0,0x10FFFF]. Both are represented as 32 bits, but UTF-32 further restricts the range of legal values.

Comment: UTF contains additional properties such as right to left etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property. Otherwise the two are the same.

Comment: See http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf32-1: “UTF-32 is a subset of the encoding mechanism called UCS-4 in ISO 10646.”

Comment: "Additional Unicode semantics" means the extra properties Unicode adds above and beyond the code points, such as bidirectionality, collation rules, normalization of forms, etc. Some features of Unicode have been implemented in software that technically only supports UCS, but those are extensions that partly implement Unicode.

Answer (score 25):

The [Unicode Standard Version 8.0, Appendix C](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/appC.pdf) states:

> UCS-4 stands for “Universal Character Set coded in 4 octets.” It is
>   now treated simply as a synonym for UTF-32, and is considered the
>   canonical form for representation of characters in ISO 10646 (Universal Coded Character Set).